# Writing dataframe as table to clipboard offsets results

Tags: r, dataframe, clipboard

I have a dataframe that I would like to transfer to Excel through the clipboard.

Using this to copy my dataframe to the clipboard

```
write.table(df,"clipboard",sep="\t")
```

Instead of the dataframe

```
                    ts sdThumb sdIndex sdMiddle sdRing sdPinky sdHand
1  2019-04-03 10:37:00  11.705  12.194   10.213  8.104  11.705 11.705
2  2019-04-03 10:09:00   5.774   7.743    8.477  7.037   5.774  5.774
3  2019-04-03 11:46:00   9.543   8.686    8.028  8.015   9.543  9.543
4  2019-04-03 12:37:00  11.205  12.850   10.107  9.914  11.205 11.205
```

I get the following when I paste to Excel

```
ts  sdThumb sdIndex sdMiddle    sdRing  sdPinky sdHand  
1   03.04.2019 10:37    11.705  12.194  10.213  8.104   11.705  11.705
2   03.04.2019 10:09    5.774   7.743   8.477   7.037   5.774   5.774
3.00    43558.49    9.54    8.69    8.028   8.015   9.543   9.543
4   03.04.2019 12:37    11.205  12.85   10.107  9.914   11.205  11.205
```

Where row number has been offset to "ts", and the POSIX-time has been offset to sdThumb. Has anyone encountered this sort of problem before?

I suspect the problem is due to using
`write.table()`
but I don't know of a suitable alternative to use.

Comment: Try `write.csv(df, "clipboard")` and paste the clipboard into Excel and then choose Data | Text to Columns in Excel.

Comment: Why not `library(xlsx); write.xlsx(mydf, "mydf.xlsx")` ?

Comment: As suggested by @G.Grothendieck, write.csv with Text to Columns worked nicely. It's a bit more work, but at least it works.

Comment: @zx8754, I'm going to paste this data into an existing worksheet with irregular spacing, which is why I need to be able to position it myself. Using the clipboard seemed to be the easiest solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would write to csv and then work with that csv in excel. The readr package is my go-to way of interacting with csv files. See the write_csv function:
https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/readr/versions/0.1.1/topics/write_csv